# Refreshed OAuth2 token has invalid signature (Azure AD OAuth2)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create an authentication flow where the user's access token is kept in a server-side session along with the refresh token, and when the token expires it is renewed if the session is still valid. However, the token I get back from Azure AD after refresh has an invalid signature, when verifying it with the same method as the original token.

Here's a runnable gist that illustrates the problem: https://gist.github.com/tlycken/fdaf47dc31e03de43a1a07fbbea2ab91

What I'm doing is basically this:

1. When the user requests a page, check for a session. If none exists, redirect to `/auth` which redirects to Azure AD, and when I'm returned I have a valid token which I store in the session.
2. Verify the token from the session using [`jwks-rsa`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa). (This normally works fine, so I'm purposely adding something to the token string to make the signature invalid in the test code.)
3. If token verification failed, and there is a refresh token on the session, try to fetch a new token using that refresh token. This request normally returns with status `200 OK` and a new set of access/refresh tokens.
4. Verify the new access token using the same code as was used to verify the old one (now without garbling the token). **This should work, IIUC, but it fails with the error `invalid signature`**.

Why does my newly refreshed token not pass verification?

*Update:*
I was able to create a simpler flow for reproducing this; the gist has been updated. It now does the following (printing these messages, along the way):

```
no session, redirecting to /auth
successful auth callback, redirecting to /
verifying old token
decoded user id e7f02a6e-510c-430d-905c-f8a0e63206c2
refreshing
fetching /me with renewed token
got user id e7f02a6e-510c-430d-905c-f8a0e63206c2
verifying new token
token verification failed: invalid signature
```

In addition to validating the token myself, I now also send a request to Azure with it, hoping that such a request would fail for an invalid token. But it passes!

Comment: My guess is refreshed access tokens are not signed. Can you verify this ?

Comment: The refreshed token has three parts separated by `.`, and IIUC the last of them is the signature (the first being the header and payload). If I decode just the header, I get the following info, `{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "AQABAAAAAADX8GCi6Js6SK82TsD2Pb7rCCqFemr3qpUpj3EJja8SpJatcDYA51CdCJueMlRpYfOo8_wofd4aSRhZ4EX0MWALK62rwaGf8oDPsIB9rXCRyiAA",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "TioGywwlhvdFbXZ813WpPay9AlU",
  "kid": "TioGywwlhvdFbXZ813WpPay9AlU"
}`, with info about which signing key etc is used, so I'm pretty sure my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Yes that's because refresh token is a singed JWT. Can you verify the kid value for fresh access token and one comes with refreshed access token ? There could be multiple token signing certificates

Comment: They have the same `kid` value. (Since I'm getting the keys from a JWKS endpoint, I would have expected this to work even if they did not - the verification code should be able to choose the correct signing certificate for each token anyway. But they do, so that's not the problem...)

Comment: just to be sure, can you try to skip first time token validation and run validation for refreshed access token only ? Anyway, all the documents I have gone through does not reveal any valid reason for the failure you face. This is a strange behaviour

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa: Even if I skip token verification for the original access token, and verify the token returned from the refresh endpoint only, it still fails with the same message.

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa: Have you been able to reproduce the issue using the script I provided? That could rule out if this is just something with my setup...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to Azure instance at the moment. Given we have verified possible error causes, I doubt it to be a bug from Azure end. May be you should contact Azure help on this and verify token signing for refreshed access tokens

Comment: I was wondering, shouldn't the refreshing of a token be handled in the same way as obtaining the token in the first place? So, why is refreshing the token not calling the callback specified in the redirect url?

Comment: @JacoKoster: No; they're different flows in the OAuth 2.0 spec. Here are the relevant docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens (docs for aquiring the tokens the first time higher up on that same page).

Comment: Just in case. I noticed that you are using the AAD v2 well-known openid-configuration (https://login.microsoftonline.com/${AZURE_TENANT}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration). Shouldn't be using the v1? (https://login.microsoftonline.com/${AZURE_TENANT}/.well-known/openid-configuration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're code is using the v1 Endpoint to obtain the initial access token but the v2 Endpoint to exorcise the refresh token. These two endpoints operate differently. In particular, the v1 Endpoint uses "resource" while v2 uses "scopes".

The reason this is happening is your calling v1 explicitly but relying on the v2 `/openid-configuration` for the Refresh Token endpoint.

To correct this, change line 19 of `refresh-auth-token.js` to

```js
const configResponse = 
   await fetch(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${AZURE_TENANT}/.well-known/openid-configuration`)
```

Comment: This is a good lead, but it doesn't get me all the way. Although the refreshed token now passes validation, it does not work with the Microsoft Graph lookup of `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` (it returns with the body `{ error: { code: 'InvalidAuthenticationToken', message: 'Access token validation failure.', innerError: { 'request-id': '8908cf4d-556e-4ae7-b0d6-7823df85a889', date: '2018-06-25T07:47:11' } } }`). I assume this can be fixed by ensuring I use the `v2` endpoint in both cases, but I'm unable to figure out what the correct `v2` endpoint of the initial auth request should be.

Comment: I wrote a walkthrough on the v2 Endpoint that might help: https://massivescale.com/topic/v2endpoint/

Comment: Thanks! I was able to reconfigure Passport to use the v2 endpoint for creating the initial token as well, but I didn't manage to get it to validate correctly anyway. However, I don't _need_ to use the user's token to access Microsoft Graph (we're currently doing this with a v2 token obtained elsewhere in the stack anyway) so I'm going to leave that as is, and be happy with the v1 endpoints for now. Thanks for all the help!